# How to display a video stream from an IP address in a webpage?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, mediaelement, vlc

I have been given a network IP address. In the format of http://192.168.1.15

When I enter this address into VLC Player, it streams fine.

The stream itself is a DVB/MPEG TS stream transcoded to MP4.

What steps do I need to take to display this in a webpage?

Comment: Do you know the format of the stream? Try http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/ and see if it works in there

Comment: I think I've come to the conclusion that I need to have a filename that is being streamed so then the browser knows what to do with it and I can embed it correctly? Is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

You should use some sort of plugin like Flash or Java.

There could be an existing player which you can use to play the stream, but I don't know any.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the Apple QuickTime MP4 codec add-on for your browser. That should allow you to view any MP4 streams.

Comment: I tried this:
<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"
   width="320" height="256"
   codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab"
   align="middle" >
  <param name="src" value="http://10.93.1.154" />
  <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
  <embed src="http://10.93.1.154" width="320" height="256" 
    pluginspage=http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/
    align="middle" autoplay="true" bgcolor="black" > </embed>
</object>

browser requires a plugin that it can't find (I've installed Quicktime). It it tries to download the stream as "application/octet-stream"

Comment: I misunderstood the question! Sorry about that!

Try this, and then replace the file with yours:

<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" width="340" height="320"> 
<param name="src" value="http://streaming.umd.edu/academic/li/myvideos/test-mp4.mp4" /> 
<param name="autoplay" value="false" /> 
<embed src="http://streaming.umd.edu/academic/li/myvideos/test-mp4.mp4" type="image/x-macpaint" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download" width="340" height="320" autoplay="false">
</embed> 
</object>

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the VLC plugin activex/mozilla plugin. Not widely used but promising.

The new plugin wrappers are on github : revolunet.github.com/VLCcontrols